# Can Android Pick up IOS Bluetooth Signals

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an android app for android that scans for Bluetooth devices. My questions are:

will the Android app allow me to pick up android Bluetooth signal broadcast and list its Bluetooth name and MAC address

Can Android pick up a IOS Bluetooth signal broadcast. i.e when i run my android Bluetooth scanning app will i be able to see the IOS Bluetooth name and MAC address on in the list . (i do not want to connect to the IOS Bluetooth)

Comment: Bluetooth is OS dependent but rather a general specification.

Comment: So does that mean i can get the bluetooth name and address from an IOS device on my list when android is scanning it?

Comment: It scans for Bluetooth devices, not for some specific devices. The device to be found has to broadcast itself.

Comment: Do you mean "can android connect with IOS device via bluetooth?", if so, the answer is YES

Comment: Yes! Why don't try this manually first? scan bluetooth device in android Bluetooth settings when iOS bluetooth is ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Bluetooth is a wireless standard for personal area networks (PANs).  Like Wifi is for local are networks (LANs).

If you have the MAC address, then you might be able to determine the manufacturer of the network interface using a MAC vendor lookup API.

Unfortunately, the vendor of the network interface will probably not be Apple, if so it would not help you limit connections to Android only devices only.

The Bluetooth name will not help here either, as it is user configurable.